# .htaccess content directory rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have php files in a 'content' directory like this:

**/wwwroot/content/about_us.php**

There could also be sub directories:

**/wwwroot/content/team/team_bios.php**

Using .htaccess, I want to show the user these files when they hit urls like this:

**www.mydomain.com/about_us.php (/wwwroot/content/about_us.php)
www.mydomain.com/team/team_bios.php (/wwwroot/content/team/team_bios.php)**

Comment: Either I do not understand anything or you do not need .htaccess, as there is nothing rewritten? Just set /wwwroot/content as the document_root and you're done

Comment: Other assets live outside of the /wwwroot/ like images, css, js. So i don't think in can set the doc root to /wwwroot/ and access those assets on the php pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # do not rewrite if the request points to an actual file or directory on disk
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # further, do not rewrite if the request starts with '/content/'
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/

  # above conditions do not match; rewrite the URI to use '/content/' as prefix
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /content/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Actually, still one small problem remains. If I access a file inside a directory within /content/, it shows in the URL: (http://www.domain.local/content/dir/index.php). It should look like (http://www.domain.local/dir/index.php). Thanks!

Comment: This one got me the closest to working the way i envisioned. In the end, all i needed was this: `code` RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /content/$1 [L]

Comment: Hi Matt, pardon the late response -- happy to hear you were able to discover the right solution for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Make the route of the domain `/wwwroot/content/`. This will have the effect you desire

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the `wwwroot` directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if this file exists in the content directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}content%{REQUEST_URI} -f [NC] 
#then display it
RewriteRule ^ /content%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```